# Update Column using Row Number based on primary key column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table in below format

```
UserID  SeqID  RowNum
 1      8041     0          
 1      8045     0            
 1      8045     0
 2      6587     0
 2      5624     0
```

I want to update the `RowNum` column based on the `userId` column as follows

```
UserID  SeqID  RowNum
 1      8041     1          
 1      8045     2            
 1      8045     3
 2      6587     1
 2      5624     2
```

How to use row number concept to update the `RowNum` column?

Note: it is just sample data. So I can't update using hardcoding the `UserId` values. I have millions of records in this table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, please visit this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would use `row_number()` and a CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by UserId order by SeqId) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
     set rownum = seqnum;
```

Comment: Gordon : Select statemet is fine. But the code dosen't update the data in physical table in the database.

Comment: @DeepikaKrishnamoorty . . . And `update` with no `where` should update the table.  I cannot say why it doesn't.  Perhaps you don't have update permissions on the table.

Comment: Fine. I do have update permissions in the db. But actually the query just updates the CTE instead of Physical table with Sequence number

Comment: @DeepikaKrishnamoorty . . . No, that is now how this sort of query works.  It updates the underlying table.